# scipy rotation: from_matrix -> as_quat -> from_quat -> as_matrix gives the output that differs from input

Tags: python, scipy

I have camera intrinsic matrix. I do the following operations: from_matrix -> as_quat -> from_quat -> as_matrix, and it gives me the output that is not equal to input:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

intrinsic = [[503.5763854980469, 0.0, 481.818115234375], [0.0, 499.7862854003906, 272.2569885253906], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
r = R.from_matrix(intrinsic).as_quat()
r = R.from_quat([r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]]).as_matrix()
print(r)

# r is equal to 
[[ 0.64746546 -0.19920379  0.7355993 ]
[-0.19920379  0.88743756  0.41565903]
[-0.7355993  -0.41565903  0.53490302]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_matrix.html):

> Initialize from rotation matrix.
>
> Rotations in 3 dimensions can be represented with 3 x 3 proper orthogonal matrices [1]. If the input is not proper orthogonal, an approximation is created using the method described in [2].

Where [2] refers to the paper by [F. Landis Markley, “Unit Quaternion from Rotation Matrix”, Journal of guidance, control, and dynamics vol. 31.2, pp. 440-442, 2008.](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/1.31730).

Your input is very much not orthogonal:

```py
>>> intrinsic @ np.transpose(intrinsic)
array([[4.85737872e+05, 1.31178349e+05, 4.81818115e+02],
       [1.31178349e+05, 3.23910199e+05, 2.72256989e+02],
       [4.81818115e+02, 2.72256989e+02, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

But the returned rotation matrix is, as it should be:

```py
>>> r @ r.T
array([[1.00000000e+00, 2.85398587e-17, 4.25286470e-17],
       [2.85398587e-17, 1.00000000e+00, 2.44541461e-17],
       [4.25286470e-17, 2.44541461e-17, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

In fact the eigenvalues of your original matrix are nothing like those of an orthogonal matrix (unit magnitude complexes):

```py
>>> np.linalg.eigvals(r)
array([0.53490302+0.84491346j, 0.53490302-0.84491346j,
       1.        +0.j        ])

>>> np.linalg.eigvals(intrinsic)
array([503.5763855, 499.7862854,   1.       ])
```

I'm not familiar with the approximations and assumptions used here, but if you don't provide a sane rotation matrix then it's not surprising that you get something different when you try to turn it into one.